# Is $S_3 \times S_3 \cong D_{18}$?

Tags: group-theory

Is $S_3 \times S_3 \cong D_{18}$?

I know that it is $possible$ that there exists a isomorphism by the sole fact that they have the same order. By listing the elements of $S_3$ I noticed that we have 3 elements of order 2 and 2 elements of order 3, and thus highest order of an element in $S_3 \times S_3$ is 6.

Ex. $((12),(123))$

Are all my conclusions correct?

Comment: You are correct that highest possible order of an element in $S_3 \times S_3$ is 6. Do you know why this proves that $S_3 \times S_3$ cannot be isomorphic to $D_{18}$?

Comment: To expound a bit further, what is the order of a generator of the rotation subgroup of $D_{18}$?

Comment: @manthanomen Not sure. I am just making observations. By your comment, I assume that there does not exist an element (or as many) in $D_{18}$  of order 2,3, or 6?

Comment: All you need to do now is show that there exists an element in $D_{18}$ whose order is bigger than 6. Specifically, show there's an element of order 18.

Comment: @DavidWheeler 18. I was confusing as to how many degrees we rotate by, which in this case is 20.

Comment: @manthanomen well, that would be r, where r is the rotation of the n-gon by 20 degrees.

Comment: So, one group has an element of order $18$, the other does not. Problem solved!

Comment: @DavidWheeler Thank you! Both of you made clear.